# Need help figuring out why I cannot change TextView text using a custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have a very simple app:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/emoticon_listview" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**item.xml**

```
<TextView />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int start = 0x1F004;
    int end = 0x1F65C;

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.emoticon_listview);
    Integer[] emoticon_array = new Integer[end - start]

    for(int codepoint=start, i=0; codepoint<end; codepoint++, i++){
        emoticon_array[i] = codepoint;
    }

    CustomArrayAdapter customArrayAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item, emoticon_array);
    listView.setAdapter(customArrayAdapter);
}
```

**CustomArrayAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    public customArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, Object[] objects){
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView;

        if(textView != null){
            textView.setText(new String(Characters.toChars(Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString))));
            // -or-
            textView.setText("Hello, world!");
            // -or-
            textView.setText("whatever ...");
        }
    }

    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

The problem is that no matter what I put in the `textView.setText()` of the overridden `getView()` of my `CustomArrayAdapter` it always displays what is in the original emoticon_array.

I even tried this:

```
return super.getView(position, textView, parent);
```

But that didn't do anything either.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: `return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);` This returns the view to display, which likely overwrites whatever changes you made to the TextView.

Comment: that's why I tried this: `return super.getView(position, textView, parent);` which gave me the same thing.

Comment: The code you have given here does not compile. The `return` statement is outside of any method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `super.getView()` at the beginning of your own `getView()` method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    textView.setText("Hello, world!");
    // -or-
    textView.setText("whatever ...");

    return textView;
}
```

This allows you to take advantage of the logic to recycle `convertView` if it is not `null`. Then you can make whatever changes you wish and return the resulting view directly.

Note that I have removed this line:

```
    textView.setText(new String(Characters.toChars(Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString))));
```

First of all, it is missing a pair parentheses which causes a compiler error. More importantly, this does a lot of work for not visible benefit. The end result is either an error, if the original text is not numerical, or setting the text back to the original value.

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh `super.getView()` already takes care of recycling `convertView` or inflating a new view if it is `null`.

Comment: Your solution worked, but I'm curious as to why the `convertView` is not the `TextView`. Why is it the `parent`?

Comment: @Brian I don't understand your question. Where do you see that `convertView` is not a `TextView`?

Comment: I just assumed, because you used `TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);` instead of `TextView textView = (TextView) convertView;`. Why use the entire back-reference to `super`?

Comment: Calling `super.getView()` ensures that `convertView` is recycled correctly without me writing all the code to do so myself. The behavior should be nearly identical to Pavneet_Singh's answer below. The only difference is that it uses the layout you provide in the constructor as the parameter named `resource` rather than hardcoding `R.layout.item`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a custom layout `R.layout.item` so

- You need to inflate that layout in getview
- find your views(TextView) and apply changes then return that view

  ```
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

      TextView textView;
      if(convertView == null){
          convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
          // to reuse view next time
      }
      // find your text view
      textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewID);
      textView.setText(getItem(position).toString());
      //textView.setText("Hello, world!");
      // -or-
      //textView.setText("whatever ...");

      // return inflated view 
      return convertView;
  }
  ```

Note : Don't use `Object` array and use `getItem` to fetch the item using `position` to display the item from array

Comment: I'm getting a `NumberFormatException: invalid int ""` on your `textView.setText()` line.

Comment: yeah , you are using custom layout , i realize it later , you have to follow the updated instructions , wait a sec , posting the code

Comment: `textView.setText(new String(Characters.toChars(Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString))));` Even if you add the missing parentheses to fix the compiler error here, this does a lot of work for no visible benefit. You are taking the text of the  TextView, converting it to an int then back to a string.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i just copy pasted the OP's code (no IDE) and one thing is important is OP is using a custom layout `= new CustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item, emoticon_array);`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh The custom layout seem mostly irrelevant to me here. You can just as easily create a view with `new TextView()`. Either way, the line I just pasted in my previous comment is problematic.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i posted the same answer (in history) but later i realize OP using a custom layout so i prefer this one better

Comment: This answer is great...as long as you fix the compiler errors and logic errors in the OP's code

Comment: yeah , that line make no sense

Comment: I realized it was from the OP's code after I originally commented about that line. I had to remove it from my own answer, too.

Comment: yup , instead OP needs to use that passed array item , lot of parts are missing  in code ufff

Comment: @Brian you were facing that issue because there is no data in newly created view so use data from passed array and old solution will work too